# How to accept java applet warning alert in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, applet, alert

I have a web page to test ,in which an java applet also runs.When i logon to the page it takes 30 to 50  seconds to load the java applet and it is showing java unsigned applet security alert.So  when i run my selenium scripts,the execution is getting stopped whenever this alert popped.I cannot able to accept the java alert because i don't know when it is going to pop.

So my problem here is , I was forced to wait until my applet loads applet alert comes, accept it and then execute my steps.Is there a way to write a listener kind of a thing so that whenever the java security alert comes it should automatically accept the alert and continue with the execution of my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to poll the presence of the alert on screen.

To correctly wait for Alert, you got WebDriverWait implemented especially for it:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); //5 seconds wait
element.click() //trigger for alert to appear
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Now you can handle the alert:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept(); //Accepting the alert
```

Of course, instead of accepting you can do something else, according to [this](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html).

Also, you can implement some simple alert validation like this:

```
public Boolean isAlertExistAndAccepted(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();
            return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In do-while mechanism something like this one:

```
do {

} while ( !isAlertExist() );
```

Comment: Thank you.But if i take the first solution you mentioned I need to call this before every action i do.I am thinking it will increase number of lines of code and also the time of execution.Please suggest how i can overcome this (or) This is the best way to do it ? (I am new to selenium and stackoverflow also pls ignore any mistakes)

Comment: Updated my answer with better way to handle Alert. I think you don't need to call this before **every** action, just the one that trigger the alert for you. So, after alert triggered, wait and accept it, and continue with your test.

Comment: The alert i want to handle is java security alert.So I will not have any clue when this security alerts pops out from the browser.

Comment: So the problem is the unexpected time of it's popup, or that Selenium Alert not handling this kind of Alert at all?

Comment: Did you tried to completely disable Java security warning on OS level? For example: http://superuser.com/questions/577366/how-to-disable-the-java-security-warning-popup

Comment: Tried to disable java security settings using deployment.security.mixcode=DISABLE. Now i am not getting those alerts.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you know where and when... it should be easy to anticipate the alert message's appearance and call acceptAlert (or whichever is the correct method name, not sure).

Otherwise, you should be able to write a conditional for isAlertPresent (again I'm not sure of the exact method name since I'm more familiar with phpUnit than java selenium).  And if present you can take action to dismiss said alert if you wish.

I had solved this months ago in PHP, when I thought the alert might be there, to get its text. If getText returns characters, then there is indeed an alert present and you should be able to accept it or dismiss it.